# SSH 'No route to host'

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding

I've scoured the internet for a solution to my problem but I've so far had no luck. I'm currently trying to set up SSH on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Running **ssh user@public.ip** returns

```
ssh: connect to host public.ip port 22: No route to host
```

Running the same command with my private ip works.

I've never asked for help online before, always managed to find a social in another thread. However, this time I am completely stumped.

**Edit 1**
- Sorry for initially poor information. Here's what I've currently tried. 
I've port-forwarded port 22. Doing so yields the **no route to host** response. Port-forwarding to another laptop yields the response **connection refused**. Removing port-forwarding to port 22 results in **connection timed out**.

I've tried turning off the UFW firewall, created exceptions for port 22 and it still yields the same response of **no route to host**.

**Edit 2**
- So the purpose of what I'm attempting is to create a server for me to host a database and website on. So far, I've got most of the database set up through mysql and now need a server that can be accessed via SSH.

I' am able to ping my public IP address:

```
ping -c4 (ip)
PING (ip) (ip) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.96 ms
64 bytes from ip: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.45 ms
64 bytes from ip: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.53 ms
64 bytes from ip: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.75 ms

--- ip ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.456/2.676/2.966/0.209 ms
```

I'm not sure what other information would be useful and I can't say for sure what is good and bad information to share. Suggestions for additional commands would be helpful! Please let me know if I need to clarify further (you can probably tell I'm a novice! :))

Comment: Your question is still pretty vague. All of the error messages that you're getting have specific meanings. But you haven't explained what you're doing or the relationship between your local host and the remote host well enough to provide meaningful advice.

Comment: Where (network-wise) is the computer you're trying to connect *from*? Is it on the same private network as the server, on the outside, or are you trying to connect from the server itself? Also, the port forwards you mention -- I presume that's on your router?

Comment: @Run5k thank you. I have merged my accounts. How do i close the thread? The problem I was facing has been solved. :)

Comment: You would actually submit your *own* answer, and after a mandatory waiting period you can come back to officially accept it.  That being said, please don't edit your original question to include the solution... it should be annotated within a separate answer.  I have reverted your last edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So either the target host is down or refusing connections to that port (eg. `with iptables --reject-with`), or you have some routing problems. You would be better off checking with `tcpdump` what is happening on the output interface of your ssh client.

You provided too little information on the server and client network configuration for a better guess.